# Update React component when state changes, using a reference to itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React component, I define how the component handles state change in a callback to `setState()`.  This seems wrong / against flux convention.  Where is the correct place to define how an element should behave given a new state?

I'm assuming it's in the `render()` method or the `didMount()` method.

In this situation, I need to call a JS method on the DOM element:

```
if (this.state.play) {
  document.querySelector(".VideoPlayer-Video").play();
} else {
  document.querySelect(".VideoPlayer-Video").pause();
}
```

I can't do this before the component has rendered. So how & where should this be done?

**Example Details:**

This is a very simple react component. It has a `<video>` element, and a button that pauses or plays it.

The state only has one attribute, "play", which is "true" if the video is playing or false if the video is paused.

When the "play" button is clicked, I flip the state, then do a DOM query to get the video element, and call a method on it.

This seems unconventional in React, since I am telling the component how to respond to a state change inside of a click handler. I would expect to define how the component responds to state change elsewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Where is the conventional place to tell the video element to play or not in response to state change? How can I reference the DOM element there?

**Code:**

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { 
      play: true
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return <div className="VideoPlayer">
      <video className="VideoPlayer-Video" src="/videos/my-video.mov"></video>
      <button className="VideoPlayer-PlayButton" onClick={this.handlePlayButtonClick}>
        {this.state.play ? "Pause" : "Play"}
      </button>
    </div>
  },
  handlePlayButtonClick: function(){
    this.setState({ 
      play: !this.state.play 
    }), function(){
      var video = document.querySelector(".VideoPlayer-Video");

      if (this.state.play) {
        video.play();
      } else {
        video.pause();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Wondering if it's a combination of `didMount()` and making use of `this.refs`, still researching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using componentDidUpdate seems appropriate.

1.Click
2. Change state -> trigger - rerender
3. Just after your component is mounted call the right function for video

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
   if (this.state.play) {
        this.refs.MyVideo.play();
   } else {
        this.refs.MyVideo.pause();
   }
}
```

If you need to control those function for the very first rendering use componentDidMount.
Simple and clean in my opinion.

**Edit**: I edited my code using ref, I think this is indeed the right way to go
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Just place a ref in your video component:

```
 <video ref="MyVideo"> </video>
```

*Updated after mark's comment*

Comment: This makes sense - but in this code `video` would be undefined. What is the typical react way to get a reference to that DOM element's instance? `this.ref`?

Comment: This looks good, except you need to use `findDOMNode(this.refs.MyVideo)`, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#refs-and-finddomnode.  Then you can run the play and pause methods using `findDOMNode(this.refs.MyVideo).play()` and `findDOMNode(this.refs.MyVideo).pause()`

Comment: As of React v0.14 and above, this.refs.MyVideo will return you the actual DOM node, no need to call React.findDomNode anymore. Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode

Answer (score 2):

[Flux](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html) is good consideration for long term components, yes it's very big and requires some breaking changes, as  François Richard noticed. But still worth it.

If you have a big component, then here's some tips:
You change state of that video component to `playing`, ONLY when video component receives $event, otherwise it doesn't make sense, as flux heavily uses nodejs eventEmitter, note video components must be explicitly separated, so when you expand your functionality it won't hurt your component.

Simple demo [repo](https://github.com/vko-online/your-tunes).

Comment: Whoever left the downvote - would be useful to know why you downvoted the answer

Comment: You have a fly problem, instead of using a classic documented available right now fly trap you should use this bazooka I made. The fly is in your kitchen so you may have to rebuild your kitchen after killing the fly with the bazooka but trust me the fly will be dead. I think it's way overkill, maybe it's a wonderful piece of code but it's advising using nuclear weapon against mosquitoes. Maybe downvoting was a little bit exaggerated but I felt the guy just tried to promote his code (which is probably great) whatever it's not really addressing the problem. Probably more appropriate in a comment

Comment: You have a fly problem, you don't know how to kill it, and you ask your friend who can kill it barehanded, but instead of asking everytime, this guy suggests you to learn the technology of killing fly. "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: I get your point but flux is heavy to implement it changes a lot of your code and architecture and logic, not saying flux is a bad idea i like it actually, but upgrading your architecture for a tiny local handler problem is far too much don't you think ? He could consider it in a broader way for its application but we know nothing about it and from "I have a handler problem" to "You SHOULD use flux", I don't get the link. Flux has a lot of implications in term of logic

Comment: _In a React component, I define how the component handles state change in a callback to setState(). This seems wrong / against flux convention._ beginning of question, he is willing to use FLUX, and considering conventions

Comment: Ok your answer is not totally off topic, edit your answer so I could upvote. But still I think that flux is made to deal with data workflows and that the answer to his problem here, especially there is no ajax call or data needed, is not a flux answer

Comment: _so that you can store video's sound volume, quality, uninterrupted time and etc._ store in localStorage for example, and this is initially a ajax(data that doesn't persist but can be downloaded elsewhere) imho

Comment: Except that he didn't express those needs and that this is not the simplest answer. However I agree I shouldn't have downvoted your answer which is, you convinced me, eventually not bad and interesting. I would like to upvote but it's been 2hours I voted and I can't change my vote unless you edit your answer.

Comment: I totally agree with your respectful opinion, but the OP was asking `flux convention without flux` thought, that's why i wrote 'you should use flux from groud up', thanks for review anyway

Answer (score 1):

Methods performed on the DOM  should be called within `componentDidUpdate`, as it is called once react has finished its updates to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Mark, so that answers my first question about where should I run it, but how can I reference the DOM element?