# how to rerender DOM on state change by other component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175209/update-react-component-when-state-changes-using-a-reference-to-itself) but don't know how to apply in my case. basically I have 3-4 input range bar, if user changes any slider other 2/3 slider changes automatically. initial values I am getting from backend. after that I have added initial values to my state. for that I have written code like this

My Parent component

```
 constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state ={
           objectiveData:[]
       }
        var {objectiveData} = this.state;
        this.props.objective_value.map((data,index) =>{

             var newObj ={};
            newObj['url'] = data.url;
            newObj['name'] = data.name;
            newObj['value'] = data.value;
            newObj['pk'] = data.pk;
            objectiveData[index] = newObj;
        })
        console.log("lcal",objectiveData)
        this.setState({objectiveData});
}
updateValue = (obj) =>{
        var {objectiveData} = this.state;
       var selectedData = objectiveData.filter((data) => data.pk === obj.pk);

        var diff=obj.value - selectedData[0].value;

        var otherData = objectiveData.filter((data) => data.pk !== obj.pk);

        var sum = otherData.map((data) =>( data.value)).reduce((a,b) => a + b,0);
        console.log("sum",sum);
        if(diff > 0){
            for(var i=0;i < objectiveData.length;i++){
                if(objectiveData[i].pk !== obj.pk){
                    console.log("object before value",objectiveData[i].value)
                    objectiveData[i].value = objectiveData[i].value - (objectiveData[i].value/sum);
                    console.log("object after value",objectiveData[i].value)
                }else{
                    objectiveData[i].value = obj.value;
                }
            }
        }else if(diff <0){
            for(var i=0;i < objectiveData.length;i++){
                if(objectiveData[i].pk !== obj.pk){
                    console.log("object before value plus",objectiveData[i].value)
                    objectiveData[i].value = objectiveData[i].value + (objectiveData[i].value/sum);
                    console.log("object before value minus",objectiveData[i].value)
                }else{
                    objectiveData[i].value = obj.value;
                }
            }
        }
       return this.setState({objectiveData});
}

 <MyInputRange maxValue={1} minValue={0} step={0.01} 
               updateProgramObjectiveValue={(value) => this.props.updateProgramObjectiveValue(value)}
               value={data.value} objective_name={data.objective_name} 
            value_type={data.value_type} url={data.url} pk={data.pk}
            updateValueLocally={this.updateValue.bind(this)}/>
```

Here is my child component

```
updateObjectiveValues = (value) =>{
this.props.updateValueLocally({"value":value,"pk":this.props.pk})
  }

    render(){

        return(
             <InputRange
                    maxValue={this.props.maxValue}
                    minValue={this.props.minValue}
                    step={this.props.step}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.updateObjectiveValues.bind(this)}

                   />
        )
    }
```

But my sliders are not moving any where even the slider user moves.so please let me know how should tell react to rerender my component? basically react should re render whenever setState call. so what I am spoiling here?
EDIT 1:
based on chris's answer I added like this way

```
 this.setState({objectiveData});
        this.forceUpdate();
```

But no luck..am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you using the parent component state in the render method? I don't see it being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So normally this type of question is why tools like Redux exist to solidify a unified state between components so not just the DOM within the component but components themselves will all be reactive to state changes.  Short of doing that... you'll need to setup custom events yourself and fire off that event which another component should be listening for to react to the event.

For creating and triggering events check out ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

You can also force components to update using forceUpdate as well.

```
component.forceUpdate(callback)
```

> By default, when your component's state or props change, your
>   component will re-render. If your render() method depends on some
>   other data, you can tell React that the component needs re-rendering
>   by calling forceUpdate().
>
> Calling forceUpdate() will cause render() to be called on the
>   component, skipping shouldComponentUpdate(). This will trigger the
>   normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the
>   shouldComponentUpdate() method of each child. React will still only
>   update the DOM if the markup changes.
>
> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only
>   read from this.props and this.state in render().

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: can you please explain me how to do in my case?